# How does an ASP.NET endpoint's result differ when using yield return compared to returning a populated collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable, yield-return

When using the return type `IEnumerable<T>` in a .NET 7 Web API endpoint, what is the practical difference when using `yield return` compared to returning a populated collection?

The following code has two example endpoints to compare the scenarios:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace YieldTest.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("yield-return")]
    public IEnumerable<UserData> YieldReturn()
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();

        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
            yield return new(
                 reader.GetString("Username"),
                 reader.GetString("EMail")
             );
    }

    [HttpGet("return-collection")]
    public IEnumerable<UserData> ReturnCollection()
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();

        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        var users = new List<UserData>();
        while (reader.Read())
            users.Add(new(
                reader.GetString("Username"),
                reader.GetString("EMail")
            ));

        return users;
    }

    const string query = "SELECT Username, EMail FROM Users";
    const string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=[db];User Id=[user];Password=[pwd];";
}

public record UserData(
    string Username,
    string Email
);
```

Comment: Probably nothing or not enough to matter. Have you noticed a difference?

Comment: The reason for my question is that I'm assuming that the context of ASP.NET matters in how a client can expect how the response will be served. The docs state that ASP.NET [buffers the result of actions that return IEnumerable<T> before writing them to the response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#return-ienumerablet-or-iasyncenumerablet). What does that mean in practice?

Comment: My understanding is that the aspnet middleware takes IEnumerable and calls .ToList() or .ToArray() anyway so it can run the JsonSerializer on the whole response.  While for IAsyncEnumerable it is respected throughout the whole pipeline and individuals chunks of data are streamed json-serialized-object individually to the output stream.